# Can an object method be used to create an object?

Tags: javascript, object, methods

Based on the initial object `Contact`, I have to create a second object. Sometimes the `Contact` object will not have certain properties. I wanted to know if there was a way to print value of `ConsentDt` using a method within an object.

I know that I could simply code `"ConsentDt": Contact.CommPhoneConsentDt` and if that key is not available, `ConsentDt` will not be printed in the final output. However, sometimes determining if certain keys should be printed are a little bit more complicated, e.g. only include `Email` in the final object if `EmailConsentDt == 'Y'`. I also know that I could write functions outside of the object to make these determinations, but I wasn't sure if there was a way to keep the logic all in one object. Thanks in advance!

```
let Contact = {
  "Name": "Kyle Gass",
  "CommPhone": "+9-999-999-9999",
  "Email": "tenacious@d.org",
  "CommPhoneConsentCd": "Y",
  "CommPhoneConsentDt": "2019/8/1",
  "EmailConsentCd": "N"
}

let Communications = {
  "PhoneInfo" : {
    "PhoneTypeCd": "Cell",
    "PhoneNumber": Contact.CommPhone,
    "PhoneNumberValidInd": "N",
    "ContactPreferenceType": "Primary",
    "ConsentCd": Contact.CommPhoneConsentCd,
    "ConsentDt": function(Contact) {
      if (Contact.hasOwnProperty("CommPhoneConsentDt")) {
        return Contact.CommPhoneConsentDt
      } else {
        return
      }
    }  
  }
}

console.log(Communications.PhoneInfo.ConsentDt);
//I want ConsentDt of 2019/8/1 to print out
```

Comment: I've edited the question to remove references to JSON. JSON is a data serialization format. The objects in your code are just JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [get syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on the object:

```
Communications = {
  "PhoneInfo" : {
    "PhoneTypeCd": "Cell",
    "PhoneNumber": Contact.CommPhone,
    "PhoneNumberValidInd": "N",
    "ContactPreferenceType": "Primary",
    "ConsentCd": Contact.CommPhoneConsentCd,
    get "ConsentDt"() {
      if (Contact.hasOwnProperty("CommPhoneConsentDt")) {
        return Contact.CommPhoneConsentDt
      } else {
        return
      }
    }  
  }
}

console.log(Communications.PhoneInfo.ConsentDt);
ConsentDt of 2019/8/1 is printed out
```